# creating a site for a medical study, need to seperate users into two groups randomly but evenly

Tags: php, wordpress, random

I have this problem im trying to figure out. At first i thought about seperating users just by their user id by odds and evens. But my client says it needs to be a little bit more random then that.

```
if($user_id % 2 == 0) {

        $u->add_role( 'control' );
    }else{
        $u->add_role( 'study' );
    }
```

Users need to be placed into a control group, and a study group, out of 10 there need to be 5 in each, out of 100, 50 etc. But it apperantly something like 1 3 5 7 and 9 cant go in one while 2 4 6 8 10 go in the other. It should be more like

1 3 5 6 7  go in one
2 4 8 9 10 go in the other.

Im having trouble figuring out how to do that in a way that scales

Comment: how and from where are the users initially selected?

Comment: users fill out a form on the site, and they should automaticaly be put into one of the 2 groups... this is using wordpress

Comment: ok - so unless you have the desired number of participants all pressing the button at the same time then their details are presumably being stored somwhere, most likely in a database? When it comes time to delegating users to groups make a random selection in the db and split the results or select all and shuffle them in php?

Comment: should be an indefinete number of participants, with them being seperated into a different group as soon as they sign up

Comment: There has to be exactly half in each group?

Comment: as exact as possible... if out of 90 44 are in one and 46 are in another, i dont think it would be a big deal

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a list of all the users. Then randomly choose an index to select a user, assign it the group and then remove it from the list. Just alternate the type of group as you go. When the list is empty, you've assigned all the users.

Comment: needs to be an ongoing, automated kinda thing